# file operations on local sever using codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter-2, delete-file

in my project i have a table named portfolio, which has an attribute called images. in that attribute i am saving the **image location** like '**uploads/1.jpg**'. **i don't have any problem with file uploading issue**.
when i delete an row from my database table, i am only deleting the row but the file still exists in the uploads directory in my local sever. **i want to delete the file also, when i am deleting the row from the database**.
i have seen the ftp class in codeigniter documentation, but the document says that i need to configure a ftp host. but currently i am using the localhost server **wamp** for my project and haven't uploaded it yet in the main server. so, **how do i delete a file from it's directory when i am deleting the row from the database using codeigniter?** can anyone help?
i am using **codeigniter 2.1.0 and mySQL** database for my project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `unlink()` function. 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php

Ex:

```
unlink('path/to/file.jpg');
```